# Formatting Date in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, date-formatting

I am building a report in reporting services. I would like the title of the report to read:

Audit Log - June 1, 2011 to June 6, 2011

Currently I have it reading:

Audit Log - 06/01/2011 to 06/06/2011

The expression I'm using is

```
="Audit Log - " + Parameters!DateStart.Value + " To " + Parameters!DateEnd.Value
```

I'm sure this is pretty easy I'm just fairly new to using reporting services. I'm building the report in visual studio 2005 if it makes a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Format()` function as follows:

```
="Audit Log: " + Format(Parameters!DateStart.Value,"MMMM dd, yyyy") + " To " + =Format(Parameters!DateEnd.Value,"MMMM dd, yyyy")
```